# Apply custom function to pandas DataFrame returns 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, typeerror

Hej,

My first post here. I was trying to find similar problem in here but without a success. Here it goes.
I have a few separate pandas DataFrames where at least one column contains dictionary i.e.

```
fiscalYear | prodID | position
2020       | 123    | {'description': 'Customer Operations', 'code': '51254185'}
2020       | 456    | {'description': 'Support', 'code': '50544654'}
...
```

I can transform dictionary column to two (or more) columns with this:

```
position_df['position'] = main_df['position'].apply(lambda x: dict(eval(x)))
position_df = position_df['position'].apply(pd.Series)
position_df.rename(columns={'des': 'position_name', 'code':'positionID'},inplace=True)

result = pd.concat([main_df, position_df], axis=1, join="inner")
```

so I get

```
fiscalYear| prodID| position                                           | position_name         | posID
2020      | 123   | {'des': 'Customer Operations', 'code': '51254185'} | 'Customer Operations' | 51254185
2020      | 456   | {'des': 'Support', 'code': '50544654'}             | 'Support',            | 50544654
...
```

I created custom function and only change input but I got *TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable*

Here is my function and the call

```
    def dictionary_to_columns(dic_column,rename_col,df):
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
        # todo: # of items in the dictionary in dic_column
        temp_df['temporary'] = df[dic_column].apply(lambda x: dict(eval(x)))
        temp_df = temp_df['temporary'].apply(pd.Series)
        temp_df.rename(columns=rename_col,inplace=True)
        result = pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=1, join="inner")
        return result

    main_df['position'] = main_df['position'].apply(dictionary_to_columns('position',{'des': 'name', 'code':'ID'},main_df))
```

I think that I get the error on the return statement. I printed top 5 rows before return and it looked okay. Any suggestions?

Comment: apply expects a callable object ... your function(`dictionary_to_columns`) returns a dataframe ... dataframes are not callable object

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking a dict into columns is as simple as returning a series from `apply`:

```
df

   fiscalYear  prodID                                           position
0        2020     123  {'description': 'Customer Operations', 'code':...
1        2020     456     {'description': 'Support', 'code': '50544654'}

df[['name', 'ID']] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row['position']), axis=1)

df

   fiscalYear  prodID                                           position                 name        ID
0        2020     123  {'description': 'Customer Operations', 'code':...  Customer Operations  51254185
1        2020     456     {'description': 'Support', 'code': '50544654'}              Support  50544654
```

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work. I get "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key". Anyway, I solved my problem. See explanation above

Answer (score -1):

I decided to answer my own question as I found a solution. Maybe others will use it.

Following @Joran suggestion/advice that I return a DataFrame I change a bit the function to:

```
    def dictionary_to_columns(dic_column, rename_col, df):
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
        # todo: # of items in the dictionary in dic_column
        temp_df['temporary'] = df[dic_column].apply(lambda x: dict(eval(x)))
        temp_df = temp_df['temporary'].apply(pd.Series)
        temp_df.rename(columns=rename_col, inplace=True)
        df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=1, join="inner")
```

Instead of assigning to a result variable and returning that I change the original DataFrame. What I think was the most important is to change the way I call it to:

```
dictionary_to_columns('position',{'des': 'name', 'code':'ID'},main_df)
```

It works well for me.